# How to unmount an usb stick from a script which is on the usb stick?

Tags: shell-script, usb

How I can I unmount a usbstick right from the script which does kill itself.

Because i'm running the script from the stick it's not possible to just unmount it because theres always the error: device or ressource busy.
So what is the easiest way: Should I execute a script on the machine through my script right before it kills itself?

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you need to run the script _on_ the disk or is running it _from_ the disk enough? Is there any reason to have an open shell session accessing files or directories on the disk?

Answer (score 1):

you can't umount a filesystem if you are using it.

you might try

```
(echo fuser -ku /dev/xxx ; echo umount/dev/xxx ) |
at now +5 sec
exit
```

- this piece of code musn't be run from usb device of course.
- pipe symbol (`|`) must be last char of the line.
- I suppose you know what to use in place of xxx.

Answer (score 1):

Run the `umount` command from a process that doesn't have any file open on the removable drive. In particular, this must not be a shell script on the drive. A script passed on the `sh` command line is fine. The script stored on the drive must have terminated; the easy way is to use `exec` to replace the shell running the script by the shell running the unmount sequence.

```
#!/bin/sh
mount_point=$(df -P "$0" | awk 'NR==2 {print $6}')
… # do stuff involving the files on the drive
exec sh -c 'cd /; umount "$0"' "$mount_point"
```